# Can't resolve '@ionic-native/core' in '\node_modules\@ionic-native\qr-scanner'

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am currently working on PWA using Ionic 5 and React 17. I want to add QR code scanner to the app. I tried installing QR Scanner plugin for ionic using:

```sh
npm install cordova-plugin-qrscanner
npm install @ionic-native/qr-scanner
ionic cap sync
```

But restarting the app shows me the following error:

```
./node_modules/@ionic-native/qr-scanner/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@ionic-native/core' in '<project-folder>\node_modules\@ionic-native\qr-scanner'
```

So far I have added only import statement into my react app

```js
import { QRScanner } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner';
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: ionic/core is not included by default in your new project. run command `npm i @ionic-native/core` to add it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I saw the package didn't exist, but was not sure if it was my fault or that of the repo's. This is my first time using Ionic, so I was scared to add something that was not in the documentation.